# Looking for explanation of this return/closure statement

Tags: javascript, closures

In the return statement, in the closure, the return takes the form:

```
return (function(){...}());
```

I do not understand the form of this return, for instance, the empty "()" after the function.
This code works, just trying to understand the details of the form of the return.

```
function carFactory(kind) {
 var wheelCount, start, foo;
 wheelCount = 4;
 start = function() {
    console.log('started with ' + wheelCount + ' wheels.');
 };
 foo= function(){
    console.log('...' + wheelCount);
 }

// Closure created here.
 return (function() {
    return {
        make: kind,
        wheels: wheelCount,
        startEngine: start,
        foo: foo
    };
}());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That creates a closure and then immediately executes it. It's exactly the same as:

```
var closure = function() {
  return {
    make: kind,
    wheels: wheelCount,
    startEngine: start,
    foo: foo
   };
};
var result_of_running_closure = closure();
return result_of_running_closure;
```

This is a fairly common thing to do in order to have [private properties in JavaScript](http://lupomontero.com/using-javascript-closures-to-create-private-scopes/). As far as I can tell, in this particular case it isn't necessary as the author of the code ends up exposing everything, but it is, in general, a useful technique.